# What wrong is MPEG-DASH format?

Tags: live, mpeg-dash

I'll try to setting a live streaming by MPEG-DASH.

There are some files for MEPG-DASH.

```
elemental-3703198892.m4a  elemental-3703228922.m4v  elemental-3703266460.m4a
elemental-3703198892.m4v  elemental-3703236430.m4a  elemental-3703266460.m4v
elemental-3703206400.m4a  elemental-3703236430.m4v  elemental-3703273967.m4a
elemental-3703206400.m4v  elemental-3703243937.m4a  elemental-3703273967.m4v
elemental-3703213907.m4a  elemental-3703243937.m4v  elemental-init.m4a
elemental-3703213907.m4v  elemental-3703251445.m4a  elemental-init.m4v
elemental-3703221415.m4a  elemental-3703251445.m4v  elemental-raw.m4a
elemental-3703221415.m4v  elemental-3703258952.m4a  elemental-raw.m4v
elemental-3703228922.m4a  elemental-3703258952.m4v  elemental.mpd
```

elemental.mpd is as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MPD
    type="dynamic"
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    availabilityStartTime="2017-04-27T11:22:32+08:00"
    availabilityEndTime="2017-04-27T11:23:17+08:00"
    minimumUpdatePeriod="PT5S"
    minBufferTime="PT5S"
    timeShiftBufferDepth="PT0H0M0.00S"
    suggestedPresentationDelay="PT10S"
    profiles="urn:hbbtv:dash:profile:isoff-live:2012,urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff
-live:2011"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2011/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 DASH-MPD.xsd">
  <Period start="PT0S" id="dash">
    <AdaptationSet
        id="1"
        segmentAlignment="true"
        maxWidth="1280"
        maxHeight="720"
        maxFrameRate="23">
      <Representation
          id="elemental_H264"
          mimeType="video/mp4"
          codecs="avc1.4d401f"
          width="1280"
          height="720"
          frameRate="23"
          sar="1:1"
          startWithSAP="1"
          bandwidth="5000000">
        <SegmentTemplate
            presentationTimeOffset="0"
            timescale="1000"
            media="elemental-$Time$.m4v"
            initialization="elemental-init.m4v">
          <SegmentTimeline>
             <S t="3703228922" d="7508"/>
             <S t="3703236430" d="7507"/>
             <S t="3703243937" d="7508"/>
             <S t="3703251445" d="7507"/>
             <S t="3703258952" d="7508"/>
             <S t="3703266460" d="7507"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet
        id="2"
        segmentAlignment="true">
      <AudioChannelConfiguration
          schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011"
          value="1"/>
      <Representation
          id="elemental_AAC"
          mimeType="audio/mp4"
          codecs="mp4a.40.2"
          audioSamplingRate="48000"
          startWithSAP="1"
          bandwidth="96000">
        <SegmentTemplate
            presentationTimeOffset="0"
            timescale="1000"
            media="elemental-$Time$.m4a"
            initialization="elemental-init.m4a">
          <SegmentTimeline>
             <S t="3703228922" d="7508"/>
             <S t="3703236430" d="7507"/>
             <S t="3703243937" d="7508"/>
             <S t="3703251445" d="7507"/>
             <S t="3703258952" d="7508"/>
             <S t="3703266460" d="7507"/>
          </SegmentTimeline>
        </SegmentTemplate>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
  </Period>
</MPD>
```

Using dash.js, but playback doesn't work.
In developer console of Chrome browser, video.js repeat to read elemental.mpd.

What wrong is MPEG-DASH?

Comment: In this link http://developers-club.com/posts/204666/ explain how do that
I did it and working good with nginx server

Comment: I tried the reference URL you taught. I did dash.js by clone. 
Just repeating elemental.mpd without changing the state, there is no error and it is on a white screen. One thing is different before, first read elemental.mpd, then read elemental-init.m4 and elemental-init.m4a once, then repeat reading only elemental.mpd.

Comment: Apparently it seems to be affected by cache and ETag when reading mpd. I set up proxy_no_cache 1; proxy_cache_bypass 1; etag off. But the situation has not changed. Is it possible with dash.js to request parameters with parameters like .mpd?_session = 1234?

Comment: I did re-install from nginx-rtmp-module. Live playback succeeded.